# ExtJS: How can I adjust the width of the splitters in an hbox?

Tags: extjs

My panel is using an hbox layout.  I am including "split: true" in the config for the panel's child containers.  Can I adjust the width of the splitters?

Comment: Please don't ask a question without showing your code

Comment: @JuanMendes, to be honest, what kind of code you expect to see here? For me question seems quite clear.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov As you yourself mentioned, split is not valid for hbox's children. Therefore, a piece of code that runs is always going to help your chances of getting the question answered, then we can make sense of the question even if you're not sure exactly the best way to ask it

Comment: @SergeyNovikov I think the question was not that clear, so much so that your answer does not seem relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`split: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border-cfg-split) is part of [`border`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border) layout, not [`hbox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox).

You can adjust width of the splitters with `width` (percentage or absolute value) config.

*For `hbox` layout you can use [`flex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox-cfg-flex) config.*

Answer (score 0):

For HBox, you are supposed to add `splitter`s in between your elements. You can then just set its `width`

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18h2

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        text: 'column 1',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'splitter',
        width: 20,
        style: 'border: 1px solid green'
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        text: 'column 2',
        flex: 2
    }]
})
```

Comment: The number of items in my hbox is dynamic, so using "split: true" in each panel's config is very convenient, even if it's not technically supported.  I had considered your approach before writing the question, but wanted to eliminate the possibility that I could affect the width while still using "split: true".

Comment: @JimNorman Hard to tell what you mean when you don't post your code; just adding `split` to items in a hbox layout does not create splitters for me

Comment: You expected me to post code that demostrates dynamically adding panels to an hbox?  That would've been noise on top of the issue at hand.

Comment: @JimNorman Did  you see the example I posted? That's simple enough, I'm sure you can come up with a good example that strips any noise away. Again, questions without code that can be run aren't the best questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If adding split: true to items in your hbox doesn't create splitters -- interesting.  I'll add a fiddle.  I'm suspecting that items of xtype: 'container' react to it better than xtype: 'label'.